# AWS API Gateway as Proxy for SQS - Data arrives without positive sign

Tags: json, amazon-sqs, aws-api-gateway

I created an API gateway that receives JSON data and posts it to SQS queue.
My problem is: if I post data with a POSITIVE SIGNAL (+), for example, **{"date": "25 + 2"}**  the positive signal is replaced by a space, the data arrives in the SQS queue like this: **{"date": "25 2"}**.

Although, if I send this same message **{"date": "25+2"}** through the AWS console, the message is received unchanged, with a plus sign.

**Why?**

**Do I need to add additional configuration?**

My API Gateway Configuration:

[image]

My Post:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyyy' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"data": "25+2"}'
```

Data received in the SQS queue:

[image]

P.S: When I get this message through an application like .NET C#, the data also arrives without the positive signal.

Answer (score 10):

After the help of a friend and carefully reading the AWS documentation, I found the solution.

The AWS SQS queue expects to receive the message in `www-form-urlencoded` format and not a JSON (or XML) format.

Therefore, we have two solutions for the case of the question:

1. When calling the API already send the encoded message.
2. Or... configure the template in API Gateway to convert the message received in the body to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, using the `$util.urlEncode` function, as shown below:

Mapping template:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)
```

Comment: This was just what I was looking for, however, APIGateway seems to be dropping the MessageBody now that I'm using the util function..  still looking.

Comment: I moved the MessageBody key to before the MessageGroupId key and it work. Couldn't be last for some reason.

Comment: @TristanPerotti did you ever end up solving this? Moved message body to before `Action